# IP-вычисления

Tags: ip, сеть

Как из IP-адреса своего компьютера вычислить маску сети,адрес сети,широковещательный адрес сети и кол-во компьютеров сети?

Answer (score 1):

Мож по IP **и** маске вычислить?

Запишем маску и IP в битовом виде, где X - это 0 или 1.

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX - IP-адрес

**11111111.11111111.11111111**.00000000 - Маска подсети (в данном случае 255.255.255.0)

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.**00000000** - Адрес сети (накладываем битовую маску на IP, все, что оказалось под 0 в маске обнуляется)

**00000000.00000000.00000000**.XXXXXXXX - Адрес хоста (накладываем битовую маску на IP наоборот)

XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXX.**11111111** - Широковещательный адрес (вычисляется как адрес сети, но то, что оказалось вне адреса не обнуляется, а выставляются все единицы)

Comment: @Free_ze если сеть "законного" класса A, B или C, то можно. Но вероятность этого меньше единицы. А вот что значит "количество компьютеров в сети"?

Comment: @alexlz
Меня смутило слово "своего", потому рассматриваю сферическую сеть без классов)
__Количество компьютеров в сети__
Если мы представим широковещательный адрес и адрес сети в виде единого числа (без разбития на октеты, пусть это будет число A и число B), то количество хостов = A - B - (кол-во "сервисных" адресов, вроде широковещательного и ). Т.е. для 192.168.0.1/24, широковещательный - 192.168.0.255, адрес сети - 192.168.0.0, то кол-во хостов будет 254 (всего адресов 256 - 2 = 254).

Comment: @Free_ze т.е. максимальное количество хостов...

Comment: @alexlz
Да, спасибо.