# IP-вычисления

Tags: ip, сеть

Как из IP-адреса своего компьютера вычислить маску сети,адрес сети,широковещательный адрес сети и кол-во компьютеров сети?

Comment: ОС своего компьютера?

Comment: Да,у меня WIndows 7 на своем компе

Comment: > кол-во компьютеров сетиМожет быть, *максимальное* количество компьютеров в сети? А то звучит типа "как у розетки узнать, сколько розеток в доме" ;)Ну, и, да, помимо ipconfig /all, есть в Gугле ip-калькуляторы:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [IP-вычисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/307221/ip-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 2):

Для получения адреса и маски используйте команду ipconfig. Там в выводе есть:

```
IPv4-адрес. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.31.204Маска подсети . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

Всё остальное можно подсчитать воспользовавшись калькулятором сетей, например этим: `http://jodies.de/ipcalc`

или этим:   `http://www.ip-ping.ru/netcalc/`

Answer (score 1):

> Как из IP-адреса своего компьютера вычислить маску сети,адрес сети,широковещательный адрес сети и кол-во компьютеров сети?

из одного лишь ip-адреса «вычислить» что-либо из перечисленного — невозможно.

можно лишь выдвинуть гипотезы. с той или иной долей вероятности.

например:

ip-адрес — 127.0.0.1

гипотеза: **возможно**, это ipv**4**-адрес, а маска сети **может** быть восемь бит, а может быть и совершенно иной, в теоретических пределах для ipv4 сети — от нуля до тридцати двух бит.